# when a menu item is clicked on smartphone, first it should change its color then go to the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu

I want to change the color of menu item on smart phone when it is clicked before redirecting to the other page. I have used different tactics but no one is successful. Here is the code/scripts I have used

```
jQuery(document).on('click touchstart','.mobile-menu a',function(){
    jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
    });


    jQuery(document).on('click touchstart','div.text_only',function(){
    jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
    });


    jQuery("body").delegate(".text_only", "click", function () {

        jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
    });


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery(".mobile-menu a").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
}); 
});


jQuery(document).on("mousedown", ".mobile-menu a", function () {
    jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
});


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.mobile-menu a').on('click touchstart', function() {
        jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
    });
});


jQuery( document ).on( "vclick", ".mobile-menu a", function() {
  jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
  });


  jQuery(".mobile-menu a").bind("click touchstart", function() {
  jQuery(this).css('color','#9e1b64');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".mobile-menu a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(e.target).css({'color','#9e1b64'});
setTimeout('window.location.href='+$(e.target).attr('href'), 1000);
    });
```